# while authenticating with foursquare, it returns 'invalid_request'

Tags: ios, redirect, foursquare

It is clear to me that this error is because of the wrong redirect_uri I have used. But what should I use for redirect_uri ? I just created an application in FourSquare, and I got the consumer token and consumer secret. I filled in a URL in the callback URL field. Now when I pick up this URL and set it as my redirect_uri, it is still invalid.

Can tell me how exactly should this be used? I found out that with OAuth2.0, you need to register the redirect_uri for safety of the user. Now how do I do that registration?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback URL is the "redirect_uri". Make sure you've URI-encoded the parameter and that you haven't changed the url scheme by mistake (http vs https)